# Does $ \lim_{n \to 0} \frac{f(n)-f(-n)}{n} $ exist for smooth functions?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a (sufficiently) smooth function. I want to know if
$$
\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{f(n)-f(-n)}{n}
$$
always exists and is computable. I was think that one could use the definition of a derivative somehow or perhaps the mean value theorem? If the answer is no, what other assumptions do we need? Boundedness for instance?

Comment: *Hint:* $\frac{f(n)-f(-n)}{n}=\frac{f(n)-f(0)}{n}-\frac{f(-n)-f(0)}{n}$

Comment: Ah, so the limit simply becomes $f'(0)-f'(0)=0$, right?